# What's a synonym to "Stack Exchange"?

Tags: synonyms

What 2 words can be used as an alternative to *Stack Exchange* and have roughly the same meaning?

Comment: *Stack Exchange* is a **name**; its "meaning" is the system of internet sites which it designates, so only another name would have the same meaning.  "Fred Johnson" would qualify -- if we started calling SE that. (The name derives, I have always assumed, from a witty variation on *stock exchange*.)

Comment: And since “stack exchange” is two words and has precisely the meaning you’re looking for why do you need two different words?

Comment: @StoneyB A cross between _stack overflow_ (a programming term and the name of the original SE site) and _stock exchange_, yes.

Comment: ... Heap swap ...

Comment: How about "LIFO Swap"?

Comment: [There's a list here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/287315).

Comment: I think this was a good question. I believe the generic term for sites such as the ones in the Stack Exchange family is a _knowledge exchange_. I believe that is the term that Joel Spolsky and Jeff Atwood used to use when they were talking about it on their podcast and blogs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want each individual word to have the same meaning, I guess pile trading.
If you want the entire phrase to have the same meaning perhaps information trading.